# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate

We have a .Net 2.0 web app which uses a third party assembly to make a webservice call from our web page running at the server to the third party site.  The call is made over https.  This code has been running without an issue for years until about 2 weeks ago. The vendor did update their certs within the last month. However no other client has reported an issue and some of our own machines work without an issue. On *some* of our servers when the call is made we get The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. On other servers there is no issue.  The servers are all Windows 2003 running the same code base.  We turned on .Net tracing and captured traces on a good server and two bad ones.  We've verified the certificate being returned to all the servers is the same.  The .Net trace shows one of the InitializeSecurityContext calls returning with a returned code=Illegal Message.  I've verified schannel.dll, secur32.dll, and system.net.dll are the same versions on all servers. I've also verified that the CA is Trusted (its Verisign).

**At this point I'm looking for any troubleshooting ideas.**

Log excerpts below.  The first is from a server that gets the error.  Note that in the logs for the bad servers the byte receive sequence is always 204, 5, 2, error.  On the good server the byte sequence is always 204, 5, 1, continueneeded.

**Bad Server**

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] Exiting Socket#50912888::Send()         -> 204#204

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] Socket#50912888::Receive()

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] Data from Socket#50912888::Receive

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] 00000000 : 15 03 00 00 02                                  : .....

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] Exiting Socket#50912888::Receive()      -> 5#5

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] Socket#50912888::Receive()

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] Data from Socket#50912888::Receive

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] 00000005 : 02 28                                           : .(

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] Exiting Socket#50912888::Receive()      -> 2#2

System.Net Information: 0 : [15784] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 10709bc8:189fc88, targetName = transform.documentmailbox.net, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)

System.Net Information: 0 : [15784] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [15784] Socket#50912888::Dispose()

System.Net Error: 0 : [15784] Exception in the HttpWebRequest#44205226:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

System.Net Error: 0 : [15784] Exception in the HttpWebRequest#44205226::EndGetRequestStream - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

**Good Server:**

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Exiting Socket#56654665::Send()  -> 204#204

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Socket#56654665::Receive()

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Data from Socket#56654665::Receive

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] 00000000 : 14 03 00 00 01                                  : .....

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Exiting Socket#56654665::Receive()       -> 5#5

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Socket#56654665::Receive()

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Data from Socket#56654665::Receive

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] 00000005 : 01                                              : .

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Exiting Socket#56654665::Receive()       -> 1#1

System.Net Information: 0 : [0244] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = b2310:174420, targetName = transform.documentmailbox.net, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)

System.Net Information: 0 : [0244] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=ContinueNeeded).

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Socket#56654665::Receive()

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Data from Socket#56654665::Receive

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] 00000000 : 16 03 00 00 38                                  : ....8

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Exiting Socket#56654665::Receive()       -> 5#5

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Socket#56654665::Receive()

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Data from Socket#56654665::Receive

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] 00000005 : C0 44 EB FF 6A 88 AD DA-2C 5A 74 99 AD 11 CE 16 : .D..j...,Zt.....

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] 00000015 : 4B 10 29 D7 DD 4E A0 83-E9 DE EB BD 37 2F 81 FB : K.)..N......7/..

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] 00000025 : D4 9C 99 6C FB A0 CA 6B-1A 4E 7A CA B9 39 1B 91 : ...l...k.Nz..9..

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] 00000035 : 7B 26 B1 01 8C FD C1 08-                        : {&......

System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [0244] Exiting Socket#56654665::Receive()       -> 56#56

System.Net Information: 0 : [0244] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = b2310:174420, targetName = transform.documentmailbox.net, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)

System.Net Information: 0 : [0244] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=OK).

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for troubleshooting tips, and not a definitive answer, I'll post this as an answer, but take this for what it's worth...

Based on the fact that **some** servers **can** access this and others can't, I would bet that the issue is still a matter of trust on the certificate.

The certificate may have been issued by Verisign, and may well be trusted on most machines, but that does ***NOT*** mean that it's trusted on all machines.

We had similar issues about 6 months ago when we updated the certs on our primary web server. We took in several calls from customers, and in each case, the resolution was to have them go to Windows Updates and look for a Root Certificates update OR google for the most recent update and download it from Microsoft.  Apparently, for some reason, the Root Certificate Updates are not always applied in the normal Update process.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to tell if a Windows 2003 server has the latest Root Certs? The service that is suppose to keep these up to date is installed. The Windows Update site only has cert update packages for XP.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't know for sure how to tell.  That might be a question for the guys at Serverfault.com BUT I do know that you can find the latest root certificate updates of you search the Microsoft download site http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=root+certificate+updates&displaylang=en&stype=s_basic